# Two different opinions on whether a topological vector space is a uniform space

Tags: convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Van de Vel's [Theory on Convexity Structures](http://books.google.com/books?id=oDUmytVzSPMC&lpg=PA307&ots=v96q_S5iYo&dq=Proposition.%20Let%20%24X%24%20be%20a%20topological%20vector%20space%2C%20equipped%20with%20the%20%20standard%20convexity%20and%20with%20the%20canonical%20translation-invariant%20uniformity.&pg=PA307#v=onepage&q&f=false) says a TVS is uniform iff it is locally convex:

> 3.10.1. Proposition. Let $X$ be a topological vector space, equipped with the 
>   standard convexity and with the canonical translation-invariant uniformity. Then **$X$ is uniform iff it is locally convex.** If, in addition, $X$ is (topologically) metrizable, then it is metrizable as a convex structure.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space) says a TVS is uniform:

> a topological vector space (also called a linear topological space) is one of the basic structures investigated in functional analysis. As the name suggests the space **blends a topological structure (a uniform structure to be precise)** with the algebraic concept of a vector space.

So I guess I mess things up again. What am I missing?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I do not know what the first reference means by "is uniform" but it clearly isn't "is equipped with a uniformity" because that is already stated to be the case in the hypotheses. The second reference is correct. More generally, every topological group has a canonical uniformity on it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: You seem right. Two possibilities: (1) Is " the canonical translation-invariant uniformity" the one induced by the TVS itself? (2) Can "is uniform" mean "is convexity-compatibly uniform"? I don't quite understand the proof, but it seems possible.